# HTML to PDF on Azure for large volume of files generated

Tags: pdf, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking for the best component to generate HTML to PDF either through an app_service or a function hosted in Azure.
We have a large volume of PDFs to generate, on average 2000 per days but this number increases month on month.
Therefore we are looking for the best combination based on performance and capability to design our PDFs that provides an acceptable look and feel.
Finally each file size is always between 30 and 80 kB

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: You should be looking for [what topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the [Help]. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: For recommendations try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

All Azure Web Apps (as well as Mobile App/Services, WebJobs and Functions) run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available.

You may checkout these options:

Microsoft SQL Reporting Framework manually generating PDFs
This usage pattern does not work for Free/Shared plans due to the sandbox. However, a small set of APIs are opened for use in Basic+ plans; these APIs are designed to enable SQL Reporting framework creation of PDFs. So, these libraries should be usable for PDF generation in Basic+.

PDF generation from HTML
There are multiple libraries used to convert HTML to PDF. Many Windows/.NET specific versions leverage IE APIs and therefore leverage User32/GDI32 extensively. These APIs are largely blocked in the sandbox (regardless of plan) and therefore these frameworks do not work in the sandbox.

The following PDF generators are supported:

•   SQL Reporting framework: requires the site to run in Basic or higher (not that this currently does not work Functions apps)

•   EVOPDF: See http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx for vendor solution

•   Telerik reporting: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.

•   Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.

•   NReco PdfGenerator (wkhtmltopdf): requires subscription plan Basic or high

For more details: (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).